# Linux validating input

Tags: linux, string, input

I am trying to write a generic function to validate input.
Primary constraint is that an empty string is not given:

```
function getvalidinput(){
    prompt=$1;
    userinput="";
    while [ "$userinput" = "" ]; do
             echo $prompt;
             read userinput; 
   done;
   eval "$1=$userinput";
}
```

This should pass back the value by calling

```
somevar="Enter the value of this string var";
getvalidinput $somevar;
echo $somevar;
```

However firstly its only prompting the first word of the prompt and then it tries to actually execute the return sentence.

Linux fails again with a simple requirement - are there any libraries which can do trivial string functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urrrggg I can believe it.
Apparently BASH has no scope.
This is horrible, however means all that is needed is

```
function getvalidinput(){
    prompt=$1;
    userinput="";
    while [ "$userinput" = "" ]; do
             echo $prompt;
             read userinput; 
   done;
}
```

Then the caller can access with

```
getvalidinput "Please enter a value";
echo $userinput;
```